# Replace character while copy from one column to another column mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to Copy one column value to another column and for that I am using below query and it's working fine

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { "$addFields": { 
            "mobile": "$user_mobile"
        }},
        { "$out": "collection_name" }
    ]
)
```

Now my user_mobile column may have + and - inside value. e.g +91-1234567890. So for this number only 911234567890 should be copy to mobile column.
And if user_mobile number doesn't have + and - inside value then this user_mobile number should be copy as it is
e.g  1234567890 . it should copy same number to mobile column

Please suggest me the query for the same

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like this

1. Check if mobile number starts with `+` if it does perform the following steps else return the mobile number
2. trims the `+` from the start using `$substr` operator
3. split the number by `-` using `$split` and then concat them using `$concat`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "mobile": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$eq": [
              {
                "$substr": [
                  "$key",
                  0,
                  1
                ]
              },
              "+"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$concat": [
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  {
                    "$split": [
                      {
                        "$substr": [
                          "$key",
                          1,
                          -1
                        ]
                      },
                      "-"
                    ]
                  },
                  0
                ]
              },
              {
                "$arrayElemAt": [
                  {
                    "$split": [
                      {
                        "$substr": [
                          "$key",
                          1,
                          -1
                        ]
                      },
                      "-"
                    ]
                  },
                  1
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "else": "$key"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Test it here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/gsEYJ3KN1Dw

Note: the query is not the best solution and can be optimized. I tried to use operators that are available in `version 3.6`

Comment: i think i forgot to use `$` when using `$split` operator it should hopefully work fine now

Comment: It is showing error {"ok":0,"errmsg":"Unrecognized expression '$trim'","code":168,"codeName":"InvalidPipelineOperator"}:aggregatefailed

Comment: I tested it before sharing you can check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/o7pti4TcZx4. which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: my mongo version is v3.6.17

Comment: well that is the problem since `$trim` is available in `version 4.0`

Comment: can you suggest me what can I use in my version

Comment: you can use `$substr` instead of `$trim` check it here https://mongoplayground.net/p/D9GNQnJIarS and please accept the answer if it helped 

Comment: Your query is not working when mobile number doesn't have the + sign and - . But my data can have mobile number which doesn't have these and these number should also come in result

Comment: sorry, i forgot that part I have updated the query. its not the best solution but will help you.

Comment: Your query works fine but it is not working in one scenario if mobile number have only + or - sign e.g +91111111111 or 91-1233333333. These + and - should also be replace

Comment: I think you should format your data before storing in db. so that all data is uniform. the problem is that you are using an older version of mongodb so a lot of new operator are not available and this unnecessary coversion can be avioded if you process the data before storing using simple regex like `mobile.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')`